# start_time, end_time does not match the format H:i on form data Edit

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am new to Laravel and facing a problem with `date_format:H:i|nullable|max:8` validation in my Controller. It is working fine the first time (with a new record) but shows the following message when editing data in edit mode.

> Following errors occurred:
>
> The start time does not match the format H:i. The end time does not
>   match the format H:i.

This is when I leave the time fields unchanged (with other fields changed or unchanged). But it works fine if the time fields are edited (changed).

I am using `<input type="time">` in my form.

The data type is `TIME` in MySQL table. It shows "11:59 PM" in the edit view. And when submitted it submits something like "23:59".

I have googled but found no information though a similar question on another site but without any answer.

It will be nice if you can answer my question. Thanks in advance.

Zaki

Comment: This is related to the MySQL conversion to UTC form in the database.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. I have noticed that and solved that. I will update my Answer soon. I have solved it with JS.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake that I did not notice the Seconds (eg. '23:59:00') part of the data. The solution was just to change 'date_format:H:i' to 'date_format:H:i:s'.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation where I have to use the H:i:s which expect value like 12:45:00. Unfortunately, the time input gives value like 12:45 but I was able to get through it by adding step attribute to the time input.

Time input without step attribute: `<input type="time" />`

Time input with step attribute : `<input type="time" step="2" />`

For more information on time input, kindly read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time