# time does not match the format laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my application, I get a validation error when selecting a time from 1 to 9, which is one digit.
The source code is:

```
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'service_id' => 'required|integer|exists:services,id',
        'origin' => 'required|string|latlng',
        'destination' => 'required|string|latlng',
        'date' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|after_or_equal:today',
        'time' => 'required_with:date|date_format:H:i'.($request->get('date') == Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d') ? '|after:'.Carbon::now()->format('H:i') : '')
    ]);
```

and i get this error

```
{time: {The time does not match the format H:i.]}
```

Comment: See if this resolution helps you out:
[data edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43693330/start-time-end-time-does-not-match-the-format-hi-on-form-data-edit)

Comment: What do you think the `date_format` validation rule is doing, and why do you think passing it a single number from 1-9 will pass validation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'service_id' => 'required|integer|exists:services,id',
            'origin' => 'required|string|latlng',
            'destination' => 'required|string|latlng',
            'date' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|after_or_equal:today',
            'time' => 'required|date_format:H:i'
        ]);
```

I hope this works!